cssのdisplay:gridで文字がはみ出てしまう
「りんご」の文字がはみ出て変な位置に表示されてしまいます。
lineクラスのheight指定を消すと正しい位置に出力されるのですが、垂直線をboxの上から下まで引きたいので、height指定を消す事はできません。
垂直線を上から下まで表示し、りんごを正しい位置に表示するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
(grid layoutもそのまま使いたいです)


.container {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 2;
  overflow: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: max-content;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.line {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}
.line.vertical {
  border-right : 5px solid blue;
}
.line.horizon {
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  border-bottom : 5px solid blue;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <span class="line vertical">
      <span class="line horizon"></span>
    </span>
    りんご
  </div>
  <div class="box">
     <div>110円</div>
     <div>消費税(10円)</div>
  </div>  
</div>



※ 正しい位置というのは以下のように"りんご"がboxクラスの上に揃った位置で表示されるものだと想定しています


.box {
  height: 3rem;
  background:yellow;
}

.line {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 100%;
  background: pink;
}
<div class="box">
   <span class="line">Line</span>
   りんご
</div>




.line.vertical に vertical-align: top; を追加、でしょうか。


.container {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 2;
  overflow: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: max-content;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.line {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}
.line.vertical {
  border-right : 5px solid blue;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.line.horizon {
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  border-bottom : 5px solid blue;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <span class="line vertical">
      <span class="line horizon"></span>
    </span>
    りんご
  </div>
  <div class="box">
     <div>110円</div>
     <div>消費税(10円)</div>
  </div>  
</div>




お陰様で治りました。ありがとうございます。
